# Как в yii2-images выводить изображение по name?

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь использовать [CostaRico yii2-images](https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images). У него в бд есть поле "name", в настройках yii2-images это поле по дефолту пустое.

Указать имя (name) можно в модели

```
$model->attachImage('../../image2.png', true, myname); // myname - имя
```

Получаю я главное изображение вот так:

```
<?= Html::img($model->getImage()->getUrl())?>
```

Все изображения я получаю вот так:

```
$images = $model->getImages();
foreach($images as $img){
<?= Html::img($img->getUrl())?>`
}
```

Подскажите, как получить мне изображение у которого имя = "myname"?

Comment: А что даст var_dump($images); или print_r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы так:

```
<?= Html::img($model->getImageByName('myname')->getUrl()) ?>
```

Не проверял, просто обнаружил там такой метод: [ТЫЦ](https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images/blob/master/behaviors/ImageBehave.php#L220)

Comment: Ты, моя радость: спасибо!

Comment: @firebear Ну пометь тогда уж ответ как решение)